# How can i remove animation from few ion view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on this app where i want menu + tabs for..
i have seen on one example on codepen and try to implement it ..here's the link "look for second seaction"
http://codepen.io/kmartinezmedia/pen/mFdkB

but its not working the way it suppose to be ..

I am using the page below as one tab and the same page with different content on another tab and I want no animation to give a feel that only the content has changed.

I think if there is any way i can remove the animation from this view , it will work....
or any other way to do that,....i am trying to fix this from 6 hrs ,

```
<ion-view class="tech-view" ng-controller="hrlDetailCtrl" view-title="C Language">
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced big-bar" animation="no-animation" >
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
 </ion-nav-bar>

 <div class="tabs-background-balanced tabs-color-light" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"  >
     <div class=" bar bar-subheader tabs  tabs-icon-top" style="box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.26);">
         <a nav-clear class="tab-item disable-user-behavior active" title="Home" nav-clear  ui-sref="app.c">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-book "></i>
               Topic
         </a>
         <a nav-clear class="tab-item disable-user-behavior" title="Chat" nav-clear ui-sref="app.cpro">
        <i class="icon ion-code"></i>
              Programs
        </a>
        <a nav-clear class="tab-item disable-user-behavior" title="Drink" nav-clear ui-sref="app.cques">
        <i class="icon ion-document-text"></i>
              Ques / Ans
         </a>
     </div>
 </div>

  <ion-content class="padding spc-from-subheader" name="tabContent" animation="no-animation">   
      <div  ng-controller="hrlistCtrl">    
           <div class="sub-topics-list"   ng-repeat="hrl in hrlist | limitTo: 29 | limitTo: -14" class="my-item item-icon-left">
               <a class="item item-icon-right " animation="no-animation" href="#/app/ct/{{hrl.id}}" style="border-width:0;border-style:none;background-color:#1E824C;">
                  <div class="has-border">
                 <h3 style="background-color:#1E824C;color:white">{{hrl.title}}</h3>
                  </div>
                  <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"> </i>
              </a>
           </div>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in Ionic 1.3.20.

```
angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE').config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');
});
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider#views.transition

Answer (score 4):

Try using the config to disable:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.navBar.transition('none');
```

Comment: for me this worked: `   $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');`